# Blender 2.8 Time Nodes for 2d Animation

Tags: rendering, animation, node-editor, compositing-nodes, 2d

I am pretty much a blender newbie but here is what I am trying to accomplish:

Basically I want to create a simple 2d animation using nodes. I created this simple network which changes the color over time:
[image]

When selecting single Frames in the *Compositing* tab, the colors are changing correctly. However when pressing the play button (in the *Rendering* tab) I would have assumed that I can view a "animation" of color fading but the colors are not changing at all (I selected the *Viewer Node* in the *Rendering* tab). What am I doing wrong?

Also I would like to "export" these rendered frames as background into my 2D Animation canvas and eventually draw onto them. How can I do this?

Any information of how to do it or information on finding information is helpful

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the compositor does not update reliably. It does so on tree changed (manually), but not necessarily on frame changed. There should be no problem outputting the animation as either video or img sequence. But as far as I know you still need to render each frame. Delete everything in your scene except the camera, choose your resolution, file format and destination and hit render animation.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? I chose Menu -> Render -> Render Animation which rendered my node background to some temporary location. Not sure how to adjust the settings.  And the workflow now is to select each rendered frames and manually assign them as background for the canvas for each keyframe?

Comment: Did it at least render as you expected? You don't need to manually update on render, only when you want to preview a specific frame inside the compositor.
These are very basic settings, maybe just check out this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQXQCT_hKSs (after 1 minute) it should clear things up.

Comment: Okay thank you, just figured it out. But the 2nd part still holds? I have to manually assign the rendered images as background for my canvas for each keyframe?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by canvas, I was assuming you were drawing in a different application

Comment: I see, what I mean is the common "Animation 2D" tab where you can draw lines, interpolate between keyframes etc. I basically want to use the output from my nodes there. Or is this a bad / uncommon idea for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

First time in Animation 2D mode, figured it out though

1. top left (or CRTL + TAB) go into object mode
2. SHIFT A -> Image -> Background
3. Locate your previous render (I don't think you can link it dynamically)
4. In a properties tab (should be open on the right) go to the 2. lowest option, image symbol.
5. choose source: image sequence and define start and offset, usually 1 and 0
6. Scrub through timeline to see if it animates.
7. You can use g and s to position your image if it's not at the correct position

You have to select your stroke again or add a new one if you want to continue drawing.
Unfortunately as far as I can tell you still have to composite your drawings onto your background after render in the compositor, as the background img. does not show up in render. But double check that, I might be wrong.

Comment: Ok thanks for all the effort, I figured it out though, I simply had to add a Render Layers node and blend it feeding it to the Composite Node. This renders everythink correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer:

In the animation tab you draw in the default *View Layer*. You can include this layer into the compositing node network with the node *Render Layer*. Finally I had to blend my background image and the view layer together, forwarding it to the final *Composite* node.

Now when rendering the animation everything is displayed